# Is it enough to prove it's injective or I should go for surjective?

Tags: linear-transformations

To prove there eixst an inverse of a lineal transformation $T$, is it enough to prove $T$ injective or do I have to prove it's surjective too?

Comment: For the existence of an inverse, you need both, but if it is a map between vector spaces of the same finite dimension, then either injective or surjective implies the other.

Comment: what if it's infinite fimension? is it enough then?

Comment: No, for infinite dimensional vector spaces, you need to show both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a simple example to show that you need to check both injectivity and surjectivity in the infinite dimensional case. Let $V=\Bbb R^\omega$ be the vector space of real sequences. Define a map $T:V\to V$ as follows: for each $x=\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in V$ let $T(x)=\langle y_n:n\in\omega\rangle$, where $y_0=0$, and $y_n=x_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$. (In other words, $T$ shifts the sequence one place to the right and prefixes a $0$.) It’s completely straightforward to verify that $T$ is linear and injective, but $T$ is clearly not surjective: its range is the proper subspace of $V$ consisting of those sequences whose first term is $0$.